# Shuffle quiz questions?

Tags: iphone, random, shuffle

i have been struggling with this problem on how to shuffle my questions in my NSarray. I want it to take lets say 10 questions out of the NSarray where there are 50 questions and then remove them so they not are going to be displayed again before the other 40 have been taking. My NSarray should look like this:

```
{
    NSArray *quizArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 

     @"How much was David Beckham's deal worth upon signing for LA Galaxy?", @"$250m", @"$32.5m", @"$75m", @"$502m", @"3",

     @"In which year did David beckham sign for LA Galaxy?", @"2006", @"2007", @"2008", @"2009", @"2",

     @"In 2008, Rice-Eccles Stadium housed which MLS team for their home games?", @"Toronto FC", @"Real Salt Lake", @"Colorado Rapids", @"Houstion Dynamo", @"2",

     @"Which of these teams, won the first MLS Cup?", @"Chicago Fire", @"Colorado Rapids", @"DC United", @"LA Galaxy", @"3",

     @"Wich of these players have the record for most goals in a game?", @"Mamadou Diallo", @"Marco Etcheverry", @"Cobi Jones", @"Clint Mathis", @"4", nil];

    self.theQuiz = quizArray;
    [quizArray release];
}
```

i have been searching around the web for almost 2 weeks, hope some on can help me! :)

Comment: I'd suggest grouping them together rather than adding questions and answers to the same array.

Comment: @jakob Pipenbring: did you get the solution, if you get please share the sample project

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem once.
I ended up creating a new Class called 'MyQuestion'.
Its property is a NSString for the question, a NSMutableArray for the different answers and an int as Tag.

Then u have an NSMutableArray of 'MyQuestion.' objects, and a method for shuffling this Array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)shuffleMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)newMutableArray{

BOOL seeded = NO;
if(!seeded)
{
    srandom(time(NULL));
}

NSUInteger count = [newMutableArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [newMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}

return newMutableArray;

}
```

Either you shuffle all objects, or you have a NSMutableArray of questions only, using the Tag property you can find out about the answers belonging to the question.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but could you make a tutorial, or an example project on how it should look like. When i add the class to my project there are no NSMutableArrays.. :(

Comment: Of course there are no NSMutableArrays.
You have to create them manually...
Maybe you should have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231351/adding-objects-to-a-nsmutablearray-property)

Answer (score 0):

First of, I'd create a class with a question and several answers, and one answer that is correct.

Then, you would have two NSMutableArrays, one for *unasked* questions and one for *asked* questions. When a question has been asked you remove it from the unasked array and add it to the asked array.

When the unasked array is empty you could move all the questions back or just change the references to the two arrays.

If you don't want to move individual questions but instead have "sets" of questions, e.g. 10 questions in a group. Then you could have arrays of arrays of questions and move the entire group when all questions in that group have been added. In that case the top level array will be mutable but the group assays can be immutable since the questions within them don't change.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but could you make a tutorial, or an example project on how it should look like. When i add the class to my project there are no NSMutableArrays.. :(